# Run an exe file via windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, exe

I have a windows service which is written via c#. I want to run an exe file while I'm starting it.

The issue is this. This exe doesn't run.
The point is that the service take log an put them on a txt file.
I just get confused because the service run as LocalSystem and it store logs on a txt file (for a specific user) but it doesn't run the exe file in that mentioned user.

I just installed the service and start it, nothing happend...
best regards

Comment: If you're expecting the service to launch the executable *in a specific user's session*, no that won't work. Services run even when no users are logged in, and also when multiple users have sessions.

Comment: not even say it to open a cmd from that user? like: `cmd.exe /c runas /user:" + username`
@Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: No, services run in Session 0, which is separate from any user sessions, and you can't generally launch application in other sessions. It's best usually to put some stub program in e.g. the startup folder so that it runs a copy in each user's session and then, if necessary, have that stub take instructions from the service.

Answer (score 1):

I had this situation, I was writing something like auto-update for my application.

The issue is, Windows service is running under **SYSTEM** user and you can not run any other application that needs UI intraction, actually if you check the Task Manager, your app is run but it's **Not Allowed** for **UAC Virtualization**.

So there are two approaches:

**1- Using a startup**

you can add your app path to the startup by adding it to the registry which is not a good idea if you want to run the app immediately and the user needs to restart the OS.

**2- Using Task Scheduler**

This is a good approach that solved my problem, with windows service you have access to tasks from the scheduler.

You can create a task into scheduler **BUT** the creator account will be **SYSTEM** and again you can not run the app!

I added a task by default to the scheduler and Windows service gets that task and updates parameters (like exe path) and runs!

For dealing with the task scheduler I used this awesome Nuget package
https://www.nuget.org/packages/TaskScheduler

Comment: You mean you write a service, and while you install and start the service, the task would be run, am I right?

Comment: @ahad exactly task should be predefined, I created an small application just for creating those tasks.